# Getting result for another project?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any possibilities to get the result of one project from another project? Thanks in Advance.

I have two application. One application I have running and want to start second application and get the data from second application as we can start activity for result using startActivityForResult();

Comment: you mean start the activity as another application and get the result from that into this application?

Comment: @Pratik : Yes, i asked like this.

Comment: @SPK : you can use Intent.startActivityForResult() Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done thru [content provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html)...